# How to browse the filesystem of hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0 without download?

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I can browse the filesystem directly on version `hadoop-0.20.3-cdh3u6`, without download to local machine, (master_hostname:50070)
But, must download the file to local-machine on version `hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0`, I want to see the data without download, how to config `hdfs-site.xml`?

> the property dfs.webhdfs.enabled has been set to true

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

> localhost:50070/dfshealth.html

to browse HDFS File System, you cannot view text files.

Use

> localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp

to get older view of File System and can view files.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Hue as well to browse the data. In latest versions of Hue we read/write/update/delete functionality from hue.